# Can't write char in console

Tags: c#, char, console.writeline

I want to write a char in the console.

This is my code.

```
using System;

namespace bla
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            int d = 5;
            char e = (char)d;
            Console.WriteLine("my Char: " + e);
            Console.WriteLine("my Char: " + e.ToString ()); // also doesn't work
        }
    }
}
```

Instead I just see "my Char: " as an output, instead the expected "my Char: 5".

Comment: What do you wanna print exactly? Your code prints enquiry character.

Comment: If you wanna print `5`, why do you cast it to `char`? Delete your `char e = (char)d;` line and print `d` then `+` operator will handle it. You should _never_ write a line of code that you don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

casting 5 to char gives you 5th value from this [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

It does not show anything in console because its not a printable character.

If you notice the numbers in table start from 48 (i.e number 0) to 57 (i.e number 9).

So you have to do this.

```
int d = 5;
char e = (char)(d + 48);
Console.WriteLine("my Char: " + e);
Console.WriteLine("my Char: " + (char)(5 + '0')); // or
```

Answer (score 5):

You want `char e = '5';` to print "5" to the console.

When you have

```
int d = 5;
char e = (char)d;
```

you are printing a character with the *value* 5 which is the [Enquiry character](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enquiry_character) as pointed out in the comments to your question, not the *character* "5".

The character "5" has the [ASCII value](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) 53 (`0x35` in hexadecimal - in ASCII `0x30` is "0", `0x39` is " 9" and the other digits are `0x3{d}` where `{d}` is the digit); you can modify your code to print "5" this way too:

```
char e = 0x35;
```

Note you don't need to cast here. but if you *want* to cast from `int` to `char`, you can use

```
int d = 0x35;
char e = (char)d;
```

You can check this yourself by doing something like

```
char e = 0x35;
char f = '5';
bool check = e == f; // true
```

---

If you want the character being printed to vary, you can instead do something like

```
private void printNumberToConsole(int number)
{
    if ( number < 0 || number > 9 )
        throw new ArgumentException("'number' must be between 0 and 9");

    char e = '0' + (char)number; // '0' == 0x30

    Console.WriteLine("my Char: " + e);
}
```

Comment: The casting converts the int value 5 to a character with unicode code point 5, which is probably a control character, not the character for the digit '5' which would have a code point of 43.

Comment: @kame - there's nothing intrinsically *incorrect* about the cast, it's just not going to result in what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert `5` to `char`, following code will works:

```
int d = 5;
Console.WriteLine("my Char: " + d.ToString ());
```

Comment: You're right that the cast is not needed, but this doesn't print "5".

Comment: I want to cast from int to char.

Comment: The console output is just for checking if everything goes well.

Comment: your cast is correct. its just because `5` as char is not number `5`. and its not supposed to show you 5. look at ascii table to understand  @kame

Comment: I really wanted (char)(myNumber + 48). Thank you!